# RowSpan con ItextSharp VbNet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itextsharp

Estoy generando un Pdf con iTextSharp en VisualBasic, el problema que tengo es al generar el encabezado del Pdf, ya que no logro que se muestre correctamente el RowSpan.

La estructura que quiero generar sobre la tabla es la siguiente:

[image: Encabezado]

Pero me está saliendo de la siguiente forma:

[image: Estructura generada]

Por lo que entiendo el rowspan de la columna 1 y 2 que los tengo con Rowspan=3 no está siendo respetado.

El código es el siguiente:

```
         Imports System.Data.SqlClient
         Imports System.Data

         Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
         Imports iTextSharp.text
         Imports System.Windows.Forms
         Imports System.IO

         Dim fuenteTitulo1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12)
         Dim fuenteEncabezado = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 9)
         Dim fuentefilas = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9)

         Dim titulo As New iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(New Chunk("Bajas de Personal ", fuenteTitulo1))
         titulo.Alignment = 1

         Dim subTitulo As New iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(New Chunk("Subtitulo", fuenteEncabezado))
         subTitulo.Alignment = 1

         'Crea tabla
         Dim table As New PdfPTable(DatosGridViewPrintLayout.Columns.Count)
         table.HeaderRows = 1

         table.WidthPercentage = 100

         Dim cell1 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk(Server.HtmlDecode("LOGO<br/>\n"), fuentefilas)))
         cell1.Colspan = 3
         cell1.Rowspan = 3

         Dim c2 As Chunk = New Chunk(vbCrLf)

         Dim c As New Phrase(New Chunk("Nombre: Desvinculación Laboral", fuentefilas))
         c.Add(c2)
         c.Add(New Chunk("Nombre: Desvinculación Laboral", fuentefilas))

         Dim cell2 As New PdfPCell(c)
         cell2.Colspan = 6
         cell2.Rowspan = 3

         Dim cell3 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk(Server.HtmlDecode("Código:"), fuentefilas)))
         cell3.Colspan = 3
         cell3.Rowspan = 1

         Dim cell4 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk(Server.HtmlDecode("RRH-INS-003"), fuentefilas)))
         cell4.Colspan = 3
         cell4.Rowspan = 1

         Dim cell5 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk(Server.HtmlDecode("Versión:"), fuentefilas)))
         cell5.Colspan = 3
         cell5.Rowspan = 1

         Dim cell6 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk(Server.HtmlDecode("04"), fuentefilas)))
         cell6.Colspan = 3
         cell6.Rowspan = 1

         Dim cell7 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk(Server.HtmlDecode("Fecha de Emisión:"), fuentefilas)))
         cell7.Colspan = 3
         cell7.Rowspan = 1

         Dim cell8 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk(Server.HtmlDecode("26/02/2019"), fuentefilas)))
         cell8.Colspan = 3
         cell8.Rowspan = 1

         table.AddCell(cell1)
         table.AddCell(cell2)
         table.AddCell(cell3)
         table.AddCell(cell4)
         table.AddCell(cell5)
         table.AddCell(cell6)
         table.AddCell(cell7)
         table.AddCell(cell8)
'Create the PDF Document
         Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.LEGAL.Rotate, 5.0F, 5.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
         PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
         pdfDoc.Open()
         pdfDoc.Add(titulo)
         pdfDoc.Add(New iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(" "))
         pdfDoc.Add(subTitulo)
         pdfDoc.Add(New iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(" "))
         pdfDoc.Add(table)

         pdfDoc.Close()
         Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
         Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", _
                            "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf")
         Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
         Response.Write(pdfDoc)
         Response.End()
```

La version que tengo de iTextSharp es:

[image: Version]
Si alguien puede ayudarme a mostrar correctamente el RowSpan del encabezado, muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Logré generar la estructura por la que estaba preguntando.

Lo hice generando primero una tabla con el encabezado y otra con los detalles.

```
  Private Function GenerateContent(ByVal tableLayout As PdfPTable) As PdfPTable
  Dim fontCell As Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12)
  Dim fontHeader As Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12)
  Dim tableWithRowspan As PdfPTable = tableLayout
  tableWithRowspan.SpacingBefore = 10
  'tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Header", fontHeader)))
  'tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Header 1", fontHeader)))
  'tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Header 2", fontHeader)))
  'tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Header 3", fontHeader)))
  'tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Header 4", fontHeader)))
  Dim imageURL As String = ""
  Dim jpg As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL)
  jpg.WidthPercentage = 50

  Dim cellWithRowspan As PdfPCell = New PdfPCell(jpg, True) ' true sirve para ajustar la imagen a la celda
  cellWithRowspan.Rowspan = 3
  tableWithRowspan.AddCell(cellWithRowspan)

  tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Nombre:", fontCell)))
  tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Código", fontCell)))
  tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("RRH-INS-003", fontCell)))

  tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Desvinculación Laboral", fontCell)))
  tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Versión:", fontCell)))
  tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("04", fontCell)))

  tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("", fontCell)))
  tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Fecha de emisión", fontCell)))
  tableWithRowspan.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("26/02/2019", fontCell)))


  Return tableWithRowspan
  End Function
```